# 'main' declared as function returning a function

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

last week asked a question here about having two main(). Last night tried it and getting this error. Take a look please.
my header file(top.h):

```
#ifndef TOP_H_
#define TOP_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define onemain main()
#define twomain main()
void print();
#endif /* TOP_H_ */
```

c source file one (one.c):

```
#include "top.h"
void print();
int onemain()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
    void print()
{
printf("hello one");
}
```

c source file two (two.c):

```
#include "top.h"
void print();
int twomain()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
void print()
{
printf("hello two");
}
```

[image: My error and warnings screenshot]

Thank you guys!

Comment: Could you pull out the relevant errors? Putting errors in only an image is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define onemain main()
int onemain()
```

This will be pre-processed to:

```
int main()()
```

You need to drop one of the pairs of parens.